# Можно ли восстановить файл с нулевыми байтами?

Tags: хранение-данных

Файл в WinHex выглядит так. [image: изображение]
Весь файл заполнен нулями. Есть ли возможность восстановить?

Comment: А что было до того?  В смысле как получились нули?

Comment: Файл был удален с жесткого диска через шифт-делет. После я решил его восстановить с помощью R-Studio, файл восстановился. Размер 25мб, но он битый, выяснил, что он заполнен нулями через WinHex.

Comment: Скорее всего никак